# npm peer dependency missing: @angular/core@^6.0.3, required by videogular2@6.4.0 - it is lying to me

Tags: angular, npm

Sorry for the broad and silly question... but can someone please take a look at this and tell me if I have gone crazy? Everything looks OK to me.

> groot@DESKTOP-F9TMEHC MINGW64 /c/mobileDev/Ionic5-go
> npm ls --depth="0"

> Ionic5-go C:\mobileDev\Ionic5-go
> @angular-devkit/architect@0.802.2
> @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.25
> @angular-devkit/core@8.3.25
> @angular-devkit/schematics@8.2.2
> @angular/cli@8.3.25
> @angular/common@8.2.14
> @angular/compiler@8.2.14
> @angular/compiler-cli@8.2.14
> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@8.2.14
> @angular/fire@5.4.2
> @angular/forms@8.2.14
> @angular/language-service@8.2.14
> @angular/platform-browser@8.2.14
> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@8.2.14
> @angular/pwa@0.802.2
> @angular/router@8.2.14
> @angular/service-worker@8.2.14
> @capacitor/android@1.5.0
> @capacitor/cli@1.5.0
> @capacitor/core@1.5.0
> @capacitor/ios@1.5.0
> @commitlint/cli@8.3.5
> @commitlint/config-angular@8.3.4
> @ionic/angular@5.0.0
> @ionic/angular-toolkit@2.1.2
> @ngx-translate/core@11.0.1
> @ngx-translate/http-loader@4.0.0
> @types/core-js@2.5.2
> @types/googlemaps@3.39.2
> @types/node@12.0.0
> @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.4.1
> angular-pipes@9.1.0
> codelyzer@5.2.1
> core-js@2.6.11
> dayjs@1.8.0
> firebase@7.8.0
> google-libphonenumber@3.2.6
> husky@1.3.1
> npm@6.13.7
> rxjs@6.5.2
> ts-node@8.1.1
> tslib@1.10.0
> tslint@5.16.0
> typescript@3.5.3
> videogular2@6.4.0
> zone.js@0.9.1

> npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.3, required by videogular2@6.4.0

> groot@DESKTOP-F9TMEHC MINGW64 /c/mobileDev/Ionic5-go
> npm -v @angular/core

> 6.13.4

package.json:

```
dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^8.2.1",
"@angular/core": "^8.2.1",
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "^8.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.1",
"@angular/pwa": "~0.802.1",
"@angular/router": "^8.2.1",
"@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.1",
"@capacitor/android": "^1.5.0",
"@capacitor/cli": "^1.5.0",
"@capacitor/core": "^1.5.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "^1.5.0",
"@ionic/angular": "5.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"angular-pipes": "^9.0.2",
"core-js": "^2.5.7",
"dayjs": "1.8.0",
"firebase": "^7.2.3",
"google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.1",
"npm": "^6.13.7",
"rxjs": "6.5.2",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"videogular2": "6.4.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
}
```

Comment: Share package.json please

Comment: my apologizes for the delay sir.

Comment: updated question with package.json, I swear if I could figure out how to format it properly I would.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's lying? videogular2 has a peer dependency of angular 6. you have angular 8 in your package

Comment: I assumed I had angular 8 biu after running the following I thought I had angular 6 for some reason...
groot@DESKTOP-F9TMEHC MINGW64 /c/mobileDev/Ionic5-go npm -v @angular/core
6.13.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

peer dependencies require you to have the required peer dependency in your package.json. Whatever happens to be on your machine is irrelevant, as npm wants to know your package will work with a clean install in any environment.

you have:

```
"videogular2": "6.4.0"
```

which carries a peer dependency of angular 6. you have angular 8 required:

```
"@angular/core": "^8.2.1"
```

this means it's incompatible. To resolve this, you have 3 choices.

1. upgrade videogular

   `"videogular2": "^7.0.0"`
2. downgrade angular

   `"@angular/core": "^6.0.0"`
3. find a replacement for videogular

Comment: Thanks for your help! at the bottom of my question is where I thought npm was telling me I was on a version of angular 6, and based on the pacage description I was sure I should have 8. I was hoping to gust upgrade or even forget videoangular2 for a while. Mostly worried that i was getting this from the console: npm -v @angular/core
6.13.4

Comment: I just did a full wipe of all my drives and reinstalled windows 10. I downloaded git, notepad++, node (and everything that comes with it), MS Visual Code studio and Chrome. In git bash I see the following:

>$ npm -v @angular
>6.13.4

>$ npm -v '@'angular -g
>6.13.4

I think it would be impossible to answer this issue on this form. Should I just mark the answer as solved?

Comment: As I said, it doesn’t matter what version is installed. Your package.json needs to contain the correct peer dependency. The solution here is to upgrade videogular. You need to be running these commands from the correct directory and your package lock might be causing issues. Delete your node modules and your package lock and reinstall

Comment: thanks, I figured out my I was getting the wrong version of angular back (meaning I was getting 6.x.x back as the version and that my environmental issue, and for the videoangular thing you are totally correct. Thanks!